# How to Deploy VB.net windows form to other computer using Mysql Database

Tags: vb.net, windowsformshost

I want to deploy my project to other computer. So I create a sample project

> Step 1: I create a windows form and add button
>
> Step 2: I add this code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient 'TO CONNECT MYSQL

Public Class Connection_Testing
   

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim mysqlconn As MySqlConnection
        Dim cs As String = "server=192.168.0.44;userid=admin;password=;database=test" 'CONNECTION STRING
        mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection(cs)
        Try

            mysqlconn.Open()

            MessageBox.Show("Connection succesful")

            mysqlconn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        Finally

            mysqlconn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

My problem is my application cannot detect any database when i deploy it to ClientMachine, what seem to be the problem here?

Comment: Can the other client machine see the server at 192.168.0.44? What is the exact error message?

Comment: yes, they can also access my database using this IP http://192.168.0.44/phpmyadmin/index.php

Comment: Can you try the following connection string instead: `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;` or `Server=myServerAddress;Port=3306;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;`?